# How to Connect to redis through SSH in c#? Which C# client have that provision?

Tags: c#, redis, redisclient

I have Linux server used for Redis and DB, I need to connect the redis server through SSH from C# code. Which redis c# client has that provision?

Comment: Wait. Why would you use SSH to access your redis server? Why not connect to it using a redis-client, such as https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/?

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/817b4f71-7e88-4b62-b48a-8a5edca800fd/sshsftp-communications-in-c?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: In redis desktop managers have that option. It is actually a requirement.

Comment: We cannot open the redis port, Ths is the main reason